# docker run program arguments in aws ecs

Tags: amazon-web-services, docker

I have a working container in Amazon's ECS that runs a program as a task. I would like to pass some program arguments, as I would do when running locally with `docker run`. I have managed to do passing a new entrypoint in the container configuration in ECS, as if I were passing it in the `docker run` command line.

Unfortunately, when doing so, I am overriding the internal entrypoint that was already defined in the image. I would like to use the internal entrypoint, just adding some more command line arguments, like `--debug` options. Is there any way to do that?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 31):

**1.** If you normally pass in command line arguments to your script like

```
python myscript.py --debug --name "joe schmoe" --quality best --dimensions 1920 1080
```

**2.** And you have a docker image with an entrypoint to run that script like

```
FROM python:3.7-alpine

# Add the application folder to the container
COPY . /myscript
WORKDIR /myscript

# Install required packages
RUN pip install -r requirements.txt --upgrade

# Run the script when the container is invoked
ENTRYPOINT ["python", "myscript.py"]
```

**3.** Then when editing a task/container definition via the aws ecs user interface, you must place the arguments into the "Command" field under the "Environment" section of the container settings and **replace all spaces between arguments and values with commas**, like so:

```
--debug,--name,joe schmoe,--quality,best,--dimensions,1920,1080
```

Items with spaces like `joe schmoe` are quoted as "joe schmoe", which is why something like `--quality best` wouldn't work, and instead needs to be comma delimited as `--quality,best`

[image]

**4.** After creating the task, if you take a look at the container details in the task definition, the command is displayed as:

```
["--debug","--name","joe schmoe","--quality","best","--dimensions","1920","1080"]
```

which is the same syntax accepted by the [CMD](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#cmd) instruction in a Dockerfile.

[image]

Comment: This works when need to run CMD in docker container. I am unable to pass arguments in the docker run command like docker run --privileged

Comment: After lots of headache, adding commas also worked for me. Why is this? When I run locally via docker run, I didn't need to add commas, but maybe that is because I used shell mode and when ECS calls docker run, it uses exec form? https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#run

Comment: IE, when I run my container locally, I can just do "docker run --name myname -e x=y  image:tag ---spring.profiles.active=production --someother.value=z" and it works properly, without commas. In the AWS ECS "Command" input field under the task definition, I have to put "---spring.profiles.active=production,--someother.value=z" with the comma. If I don't it doesn't work.

Comment: As a side note: if you are using Cloudformation, the syntax is:
command:
 - arg1
 - arg2
 - ...

Answer (score 21):

When you run a task in ECS you can specify **container overrides**.

In the AWS console this can be found at the bottom in the *Advanced Options* section.

[image]

On the CLI you can pass in a JSON object with the overrides like so:

```
aws ecs run-task ... --overrides '{"containerOverrides": [{"name": "whatever", "command": ["foo", "bar"}]}'
```

The `command` is the `CMD` that gets executed inside the container.

In the same way environment variables can be passed to a container. Here's the list of possible options as described in the [aws-cli docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/ecs/run-task.html#options):

```json
{
  "containerOverrides": [
    {
      "name": "string",
      "command": ["string", ...],
      "environment": [
        {
          "name": "string",
          "value": "string"
        }
        ...
      ],
      "cpu": integer,
      "memory": integer,
      "memoryReservation": integer
    }
    ...
  ],
  "taskRoleArn": "string",
  "executionRoleArn": "string"
}
```

<sub>For some reason the `name` always has to be set in the overrides.</sub>

Comment: How to escape a comma in CMD od ECS?

Comment: `name` is mandatory because a task definition can define multiple containers, each with their own name

Answer (score 1):

You can add command line arguments for the container entry point when creating new ECS task revision in AWS console. Open your container settings, and under the ENVIRONMENT label put the comma-separated list of command line arguments into the "Command" field.

Example:

```
--debug,--packages,org.apache.hadoop:hadoop-aws:2.7.3
```

will add 2 command line arguments to your container entry point.

Comment: This should be `--debug,--packages,org.apache.hadoop:hadoop-aws:2.7.3` with a comma between --packages and its value

Comment: can i specify a -v /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock into the Command field? and expect docker run to pickup these command line arguments?

Answer (score -1):

It was easy: the command line arguments can be passed as **Command** in ECS configuration, instead of entrypoint.

Comment: Would have loved to see an example of this.

Comment: @Ducain Added details in separate answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/53434585/2753241

Answer (score -1):

Use environment section in ecs task definition to inject your configs.

```
"environment" : [
    { "name" : "string", "value" : "string" },
    { "name" : "string", "value" : "string" }
]
```

Please refer to the following aws documentation
http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonECS/latest/developerguide/task_definition_parameters.html#container_definition_environment

Comment: This is to add environment variable while starting the container.