# How to pass file key to AWS-ECS container triggered on S3 Put?

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, docker, amazon-s3, amazon-ecs

I have an ECS Task Definition which gets triggered whenever a file is put into a specific location in an s3 bucket. My ECS Task definition container has a python script which wants to process the file which has caused the trigger. Is there any way i can pass the filekey due to which trigger is made to the python script ? I want to avoid the use of lambda here.

I have set up the trigger using this [guide](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudWatch/latest/events/CloudWatch-Events-tutorial-ECS.html)

Comment: Unfortunately, the CW Events Trigger Target of ECS Task doesn't support passing the trigger details to ECS task. One of the approach would be involve the lambda here. `S3 Trigger --> Lambda(with S3 bucket/key details) --> AWS ECS Run Task(with ContainerOverrides)`. So instead of CW Events trigger, use direct S3 Lambda Trigger, within Lambda, have a python code to execute AWS ECS Run Task with [overrides](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53434585/5030709).

Answer (score 1):

This is possible with the API/terraform, but not directly via the UI. You can use an InputTransformer to pass the bucket and key in as containerOverrides. See https://medium.com/@bowbaq/trigger-an-ecs-job-when-an-s3-upload-completes-3559c44c37d1 for a write-up.